# Is this a cube?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, geometry, grid

This challenge is a riff on Dion's challenge "[Is this a rectangle?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203098/53884)". The goal of this challenge is to write a program to decide whether or not some collection of tuples of integers represents a hypercube of some dimension.

#### Background

A [hypercube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube) is a generalization of a square.

- A \$0\$-cube is a single point.
- A \$1\$-cube is a line segment.
- A \$2\$-cube is a square.
- A \$3\$-cube is an ordinary cube.
- An \$n\$-cube is a connected geometric object consisting of pairs of parallel line segments, perpendicular to each other and of the same length.

### Example

For example, if you are given the input \$\{(0, 4, 0, 9), (2, 2, -4, 9), (-2, 0, -6, 9), (-4, 2, -2, 9)\}\$, then you should return a truthy value because these four points define a \$2\$-cube (a square).

You are allowed to input the data in any reasonable format—but the computation needs to work regardless of the input order of the points.

An \$n\$ cube has \$2^n\$ vertices, so if the list of numbers does not contain \$2^n\$ numbers, you must return a falsey value.

### Challenge

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so shortest code wins.

### Test data

Cubes:

```
[(1,9,7,7)]
[(1),(2)]
[(9,1,9),(1,2,9)]
[(0,0,5),(0,1,5),(1,0,5),(1,1,5)]
[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)]
[(0,0,0),(0,3,4),(0,-4,3),(0,-1,7),(5,0,0),(5,3,4),(5,-4,3),(5,-1,7)]
```

Non-cubes:

```
[(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,1)]
[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0)]
[(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)]
[(1,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,1,1)]
```

If you'd like more test data, or if you'd like to *suggest* more test data, let me know.

Comment: In the first paragraph one can read _"to decide whether or some"_

Comment: Are you sure `[(0,4,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,1)]` is a cube?

Comment: May we assume that all points have the same number of coordinates?

Comment: @Adám, yes, all points have the same number of coordinates.

Comment: Will the input points be distinct?

Comment: @xnor, yes, the list of points will be distinct.

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##lY5NboMwEIX3PUVW1UwYHBupilBrTpCcwGJhiEmo@AmYIBr17tQhVM2iadTVm/F77xu/617btM2PnV/VOzNmchxkBI0cWFbobquPoGU0sNINiYw0a83ulBoASz3lKCPrQe8nKo9xuQyIIyKzddsBaEqcrf3EvZjetB8XEJRSrxq1cfjCVPvuEGNeLRpmi9xBOZ3lVncHVtT7AL4j6AnE59ITUp4/N2/B@PqU1pWtC3PJQQZKCQppTes4XiD@4sakgjseJ04vzuckJhXzLqb9Ds9l@Ny5qpvmjvjjzm32pyvm7tUXNyz@gBk6L5wygdP//HXKjl8) should be hacked

Comment: @PeterKagey Fail on 000 001 010 100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 44 bytes

```apl
{≡/((÷∘⊃⍨1↓⍋⌷¨⊂)⍤1∘.(+.×⍨-)⍨)¨⍵(,⍳2⍴⍨⌊2⍟≢⍵)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDBasJAEIbvPsXeskvV7gRE0rcJlBRpIEW8iHjRIjW6pVBKeystPeReRehR32ReJP7ZNRiKYNM97Pz7z34zsxvexa3rYRgnNzk/vvQSnj3pPMI@4vnHpZS7DT@8cTplkxHPntkseLnZZpxOFJsvQrItL9q7V@RbcDKFnFnLJptvn80KDi9TqHeefyKhxnk@sNXNGk4fMmLzc@VFYS/2oOD3eXHvJbfeuIEy6YREILqiq0SdNRAEmpRs@vXAktVCi45CoCKQO5E9nWWL29qxNkA4ls6w2vU9QocSruD/WG37ljPRcRhdzmRnDiCDwvERav7Vqff@idUHtsJXnlCVv/8O7B4)

the argument `⍵` is a vector of coordinate vectors

`,⍳2⍴⍨⌊2⍟≢⍵` build a hypercube as the cartesian product \$\{0,1\}^{\left\lfloor \log_2\left|\omega\right|\right\rfloor}\$

`≡/(`*f*`)¨⍵(`..`)` evaluate *f* for `⍵` and the 01 hypercube, and test if they match

`∘.(+.×⍨-)⍨` matrix of pairwise distances

`(÷∘⊃⍨1↓⍋⌷¨⊂)⍤1` sort each row and divide by its second element

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <sup><s>262</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>305</s></sup> 303 bytes

Saved a whopping 19 bytes thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)!!!

Added 118 bytes to fix a bug kindly pointed out by [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor), [Peter Kagey](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53884/peter-kagey) and [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2).

```python
lambda l,R=range,L=len:(n:=L(l))<2or(d:=L(bin(n))-3)and(p:=sorted([sum((x-y)**2for x,y in zip(i,j))for i in l for j in l]))==[i*p[n]for i in R(d+2)for _ in R(2**d*math.comb(d,i))]and(K:=R(L(l[0])))and L({sum(([sum(l[i][j]for i in R(n))for j in K][j]-n*l[i][j])**2for j in K)for i in R(n)})<2
import math
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLBbqMwEL3nK0a9ZIZ1VkC66gat97iX5hT15qKKFLJ1BAYZR2o2yrentiEJadpDFyPxZua98RvjZmteajX92ejDij8eyqxa5hmUbMF1pv4WbM7LQiWoEj7HkuhXXGvMXbCUChXRZEqZyrFJeFtrU@Qo2k2F@DrZUhDEq1rDK9uCVPBPNijZmsjlpMuU4ODaw5SIcyGDRqj0RFhg/i32/KcujIMgD6rMvHx/rqsl5kwSpW77@4Qv0BoUoW3kDMEcd96It1MKmYr1sLHqfPjN711tooKedfTd1ehCtLcHMJJVY0cF5@Ngita0wEGMwD5CYMRgxuDOvpQyeNCbImXnGjHAmF1XQgb2/eHK9hv1MDpnoz77QU/HCc/KI3TRWRk55Z@sbL8iDXvCtTS8kA74xy7R/0vD3vCgywkOJgrfDXd5LDNfmPWc2MEvHt2n53Wluhrog8SnvyDsFjHLjQa4j07YrqE@HWmOm/HjJr67fR4z6GA0HdPIXVjDCndl/e1M/GYtX6EhDxstlcHVzc7sYfIbdu0edlq0nBfp/oYObw)

Inputs a list of points and returns `True`/`False`.

**How**

Calculates the square of the distances between all possible pairs of points (including self-pairs and both \$(p_i,p_j)\$ and \$(p_j,p_i)\$ for all points \$p_j\$ and \$p_i\$ where \$i\neq j\$) and normalises them by the smallest non-zero square distance.  For an \$n\$-cube we should then see a pattern of integers \$i = 0,1,\dots, n\$ each occurring \$2^{n}{n\choose i}\$ times.  This corresponds with the \$0\$s for all the self-pairs, and the square of the lengths of all the sides being \$a^2\$, and the square of the lengths of all the diagonals being \$2a^2, 3a^2,\dots, na^2\$.

**Correction**

Also checks that the given vertices are all equidistant from the centre of mass.

Comment: I feel like this should work and not give false positives, but I don't see how to prove it. The multiset of distances doesn't always determine the set of points. In one dimension, I found that `[0, 1, 3, 3, 7, 8]` and `[0, 1, 1, 4, 6, 8]` have the same multiset of pairwise distances even though they are not translations or reflections of each other. But it feels like the distances of vertices in a cube constraints it in a more structured way.

Comment: I think the points \$\{(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (\frac 12, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 0), (\frac 12, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 1)\}\$ meet this criteria but don't form a square. I'll see if I can rotate and scale this to make it fit on the integer lattice.

Comment: @PeterKagey So after rotation it's [(1,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,1,1)]

Comment: @l4m2, thanks! I added a new test case to reflect this.

Comment: @PeterKagey Thanks - have added a correction.

Comment: @l4m2 Thanks - have added a correction.

Comment: @PeterKagey Do paths of 3 or more points determine a cube? (For my answer it's easily done)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <sup><strike>339</strike></sup> 338

```
lambda P:1==L(P)or P in map(g,permutations(P))
from itertools import*
L=len
Z=zip
D=lambda a,b:sum(x*y for x,y in Z(a,b))
def g(Q):B=[[x-y for x,y in Z(p,Q[0])]for p in Q[3-L(bin(L(Q))):]];return any(D(a,b)or D(a,a)-D(b,b)for a,b in combinations(B,2))or{tuple(x+sum(y)for x,y in Z(Q[0],Z(*C)))for C in product(*[(p,(0,)*L(p))for p in B])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVPLbtswELzrKxa5eKnSgGS3SK2CPThGTzrYQE9WdJBtKhWgB0FSgFXD3@4uFaV@pYdUIKDlzM5wlw/V2V9NPf2q9CkXz6cyqza7DJZRKESMS9ZoWEJRQ5UpfOFK6qq1mS2a2hDJvFw3FRRWats0pYGiUo22vheLUtbeWvwulLcQg2fGN5FpK9z7HeTku@edc14jEWS1kzm84IpFc5Ek@/FNjuKrJEhZ6kDloFUyHce4KWqMScRYlKbftLStriGrO1z0rpTsgoyNF7ihuVMT7vTbpiLx0MqcTxglH2yrSon7T67Mjl0V4Jbna/SfaC1HPDlY6WbXbi36CRWIAWd@jOqV74ucp@x4stJYAwISD@hLEgw5zDg80mAph5@6lSk/c4wDTvg9E3Cg8cXR9A@HMDyj4YC@4@lygrPyLXSzszJ0yh9ZaT4iDYaEe2lwJb3If3MJ/18aDAVfuPwNLzoKbpq73pZZT8yGnIkLP7h1/9yvO9VdQ@8At0eQep4W2I6e28nj5@2Iw2sYTkf07uiGWS7dHeuvV9QXYESORlq09JzcXOmitpg/HOwRxt/hYI5w0IkRQqbHB3b6Aw)

Takes a `set` of points as input.

Pseudocode explanation:

```
def f(points):
    let n = log_2(|points|)
    for each permutation Q of the points:
        let q be the first point in Q
        let B be the following n points, with q subtracted from each
        if all pairs of points in B are orthogonal and have equal magnitude:
            let S be the set of points which can be obtained by summing q and any subset of B
            if S == points: return True
    return False
```

Can definitely be golfed further but it's bedtime.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 182 bytes

```javascript
x=>(g=(q=(x,z)=>x.flatMap(a=>x.flatMap(c=>x.map(b=>z*a.reduce((s,v,i)=>s+(v-b[i])**2+(v-c[i])**2,0)))).sort((a,b)=>a-b))(x,K=x.length))+''==q(x.map(_=>[...(K++).toString(2)]),g[K]|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU7RaoNAEHzvV@Qtu7oed0IJEs4fkD718ZByGrUWq4leRUL/3Z5RWktKSvZlZ5iZnX3Tve7Stjwar24O2ZjLcZAhFBJOEgY6owwHllfaPOkj6DVJJ/JuQSLDs6NZmx0@0gygo55KG@tc6L1ElTE6jj/hdMHE0Q7rmtYAaEqsV3sJoq2L5MCqrC7MK6K73Up5grnjRYaKMQaR6yIzzbNpy7oAH2OkQkXxJ8dx/5A2dddUGauaAnJQSlBAO9rF8QZxv7mWY1L@LF5pnDg9Wp2TuGyxcHHhf2cmD18y87ZoyYgbPWvvT1Ys2VkXq1v8n5uB1YKLx7f7nl9veNf@9c@/8PdP4xc)

Check sums of length squares of A-B-C, where A,B,C can be same

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 258 bytes

```javascript
x=>(q=(x,z)=>g=x.flatMap(a=>x.map(b=>z*a.reduce((s,v,i)=>s+(v-b[i])**2,0))).sort((a,b)=>b-a))([...x,x[0].map((_,i)=>x.reduce((s,v)=>s+v[i],P=0)/(K=x.length))],K)+''==q([x.slice(D=~Math.log2(K)).map(_=>!P++||.5),...x.map(_=>[...(K++).toString(2)])],g[0]/~D|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY5Bb4JAEIXv/RX25IyM60JijDHLyRsxMemRbMyiiDQUFCjZGONfpwvSlsbGpqeZ3ffeN@9VVarY5vGxHKfZLqz3otbChZMATWcUbiQ02yeqXKkjKOFq9maWQLjnkWJ5uHvfhgAFVRQbb2FBNQ78WOJo5BBHRFZkeQmgKDByMFaI4DPGNGmfyxYFmzaq@7AWVRkOrQXHCXimQxKmUXlAlOShNRwKcQJfsyKJTWYpritVHliSRQ545moD3gj3eW1ZlwubIjU3P3@bAuBZFrIyeynzOI3AQWnAkek0uS4vHOvF0zZLiywJGybswfdtmtOMZlIOEBeDe1mS79zEO40Tp6nROdnttLu33b5/zzQe3mVu02xdxn5wp@/9ztpd9qbbPRb/gzk32rz1OGb@p@sDb9/f7/xj/@pUfwA)

Similar to [Noodle9's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204661/), but generate another square to compare rather than use formula and add midpoint like normal ones

Comment: Error like Noodle9's answer

Comment: I added a new test case to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 139 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
import Data.List.Ordered
c p=has[(2^n,n*2^n)|n<-[0..]](length p,length$group(sort[sum$(^2)<$>zipWith(-)x y|x<-p,y<-p])!!1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYw9C4MwFEX3/goFh6RE8St00U4dCx07hAhBxYRqDEkELf53G6pdyoN7D5fD48y82r7fNjGoUVvvxiyL7sLY0/8QPXTT6rY51Z4qOTMEpJVE8uwSrrIISRxFlIK@lZ3lnkI7BJ0eJwWMe0XMNASgSmERXN9CPYXlIISzt6xzESq0uKDQ9xO4DUzIUmkhbVATEiN3FLnOUP7tMEfZDgm6OMCHgQ8D/wy8G3T7AA)